# Can gdb be set to break on any throw?

Tags: c++, exception, gdb

I am debugging code with exception throwing and exception handling. I would like gdb to break immediately when an exception is thrown, so i can inspect the state of the program and the call stack. How can I make gdb break when any exception is thrown?

Comment: Use "catch throw". You also have "catch catch" to break whenever an exception is caught.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this with the `catch throw` command. See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html):

> `catch` *event*
>
> Stop when *event* occurs. The *event* can be any of the
>   following:
>
> `throw` [*regexp*]
>
> `rethrow` [*regexp*]
>
> `catch` [*regexp*]
>
> The throwing,
>   re-throwing, or catching of a C++ exception.
>
> If *regexp* is given, then only exceptions whose type matches the
>   regular expression will be caught.